# How do I get an input value to dynamically update a Craft query on each keypress?

Tags: templating

I want to set a Javascript variable using a Craft variable. Is this possible?

```
{% set searchJs %}

$( "#search" ).keydown(function() {

  var query = document.getElementById('search').value;

  {% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
  {% set results = craft.weightedSearch.substringSearch(query) %}

  {% if results | length %}
    {% for entry in results %}
      console.log( "{{ entry.title }}" );
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    console.log( "Sonuc Bulunamadı" );
  {% endif %}

  console.log( "{{ query }}" );
  console.log( query );
});

{% endset %}

{% includeJs searchJs %}
```